# HERE Android Premium SDK: Map with truck restrictions is lagging

Tags: android, here-api

We use the Android Premium SDK of HERE in our application containging truck navigation. We have just upgraded from version 3.3 to 3.8, and and we experience a quite strange problem. The app started to use the CPU and the GPU very much after this upgrade. We made some investigations and the followings are happening:

- The extra CPU and GPU usage occurs when truck restrictions are displayed on the map, that is when we use: map.setFleetFeaturesVisible(EnumSet.of(Map.FleetFeature.TRUCK_RESTRICTIONS));
- We tested such that we set all the layers invisibile with map.setVisibleLayers(), and the truck restrictions were displayed. However, the app is still very slow. Nothing changed.
- Using the map.setFadingAnimations(false); helped a little bit, but not too much.
- We are trying to solve the problem with different tilt angles by using map.setTilt(). It looks like this helps, but it is still worse than with the version 3.3.

Based on these facts, we believe the problem is with the amount of markers displayed when TRUCK_RESTRICTIONS are required. It is noted here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/dev_guide/topics/development-tips.html , that too many objects can cause performance problems. However, we cannot modify the amount of objects with TRUCK_RESTRICTION, and in cities (e.g in Budapest) there are many restrictions.

Does anyone have any advices on what should we do?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. We are working on a solution and plan to fix this within the next SDK release (3.10).

Comment: Do you have a ticket or an issue tracker which you can link to, so other users can follow the progress and probably read up some more?